# Does 1) AWS DMS handle timezone offset 2) AWS DMS sents notification when a migration task is completed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

Can somebody provide insights on the below details.

1) Can AWS DMS add time offset to table columns while initiating the migration so that migrated table has the same time in the new time zone (for all supported DB platforms)

2) Can AWS DMS sent us SNS notifications when a data migration task is completed. As far as I have checked it is not there in the official documentation. Any work around would help me too.:)

Answer (score 1):

For (1), the answer varies according to the source and target endpoints combination, there can hardly be a single answer without this information.

In general, if you are using Transformation Rule in the DMS task, you can convert your time by using its built in sqlite function, you may refer to this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Transformations.html) for more information. Again, it really depends on what your target endpoint is, in order to give you a more specified answer.

Answer (score -1):

1) you can set timezone on session level by updating the extra connection attributes 
eca
for example you can set the timezone by using initstmt=SET time-zone

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.MySQL.html#CHAP_Target.MySQL.ConnectionAttrib

But again this is engine specific. for other engines you need to check and update the initstmt accordingly

2) DMS does support event notifications 
specifically for a task stop you can configure event DMS-EVENT-0079
description: REPLICATION_TASK_STOPPED – The replication task has stopped.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Events.html#USER_Events.Messages